# excel vba : Sum up column value to last column

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Below is my excel format.

column `KZ` is `Grand Total` of all columns

```
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|.....|KZ|
2|4|3|5|5|6|2|7|.....|34|
8|2|3|5|6|6|3|7|.....|44|
2|0|3|5|5|6|2|7|.....|30|
9|4|3|6|5|6|2|7|.....|44|
2|4|5|0|5|6|3|2|.....|24|
```

There are 1000 of such rows in my excel sheet. I want to write a macro to sum all the column values to `KZ`. Please help

Here is the code I am trying :

```
Sub SumMacro()

   Dim columns As Long

    columns = Sheets("AllData").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Set testData = Sheets("AllData").Range("b65536").End(xlUp)
   ' Here I want to apply for/do while loop to sum up all the rows.
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-309]:RC[-1])"

End Sub
```

Problem : I am a beginner to VBA so I don't know how to select range dynamically.

Comment: You just want the sum of the `KZ` column? Why not just a simple Excel `SUM` formula?

Comment: no sum of a,b,c.. all columns to KZ. I cannot use simple formula because this is sheet is being generated by my macro dynamically.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider. [Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/). Hints: Google for set a range based in a title and sum loop in range excel vba

Comment: yes, I code but that is not working at all :( and not even getting idea how to select range dynamically. I will updated my question with the code.

Comment: Isn't `KZ` the sum of the columns already? If not, how is it different?

Comment: @AlexisOlson : I have demonstrated how i am expecting the result. I want to achieve it programmatically.

Comment: @SandeepKushwah As an OT: People would likely to downvote if you don't give enough info -I'd have done it too but, this time I decided to wait for the code (it's one of the intro topics and considering you have 300+ rep it's something that should be well known to you)-; its their right if they feel like so, you can't decide whether or not to downvote/upvote your question, don't insult people if they do by telling "if you are not qualified don't share your thoughts", it's their right. As for the question itself, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves the stated situation -in general terms-, adjust to your ranges/specific desired result

```
  Sub SumMacro()

   Dim Totalcolumns As Long
   Dim CounterSum As Long
   Dim CounterColumn As Long
   Dim SumResult As Long
    Totalcolumns = Sheets("AllData").UsedRange.columns.Count

    For CounterColumn = 1 To Totalcolumns
    For CounterSum = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, Totalcolumns).End(xlUp).Row
    On Error GoTo err01SumMacro
    SumResult = Cells(CounterSum, CounterColumn).Value + SumResult
    Next CounterSum
    Next CounterColumn
    MsgBox SumResult 'or debug print...
    If 1 = 2 Then '99 If error
err01SumMacro:
    MsgBox "err01SumMacro:Data in cells(R:" & CounterSum & ",C:" & CounterColumn & ") is not a number!", vbCriticalvbCritical
    End If

End Sub
```

**Edit: Working code Sample**

[image]

Comment: this is only for  1 row. I want to loop all the rows(~1000). That's where I got stuck to apply for loop for all the rows.

Comment: Did you even try it? This starts from row one from the column to the last row of that column -and does that for every column-

Comment: I am really sorry for overlooking into it.. I will just test and update you. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: `Cells(Rows.Count, Totalcolumns).End(xlUp).Row`  this is resulting 1.  So, the block of code inside `for loop` is not getting executed. Could you please suggest what best can be done?

Comment: It works for me as you may see in the writing, it should get the last row used in the column where is performing the sum in, attached gif.

Comment: Few changes to this answer solved my problem. So marking this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to use VBA when you can do a `=SUM` for each row using autofill.

You can also do a dynamic range without VBA, using the `=OFFSET` function which once again seems far easier than writing a macro for it.

However, if for whatever reason you insist on using VBA, check [this link](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/5-ways-to-create-a-dynamic-auto-adjusting-vba-range) for whichever method makes more sense to you

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it worked.  It assumes you have a block of uninterrupted values and that KZ is the last column of that block.

Sorry if the `region` variable is a little wordy.  I can clear it up for you if you like.

```
    Sub getTotal()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim region As Range
    Dim total As Integer

    Set region = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 1)
    total = 0

    For Each cell In region
        total = total + cell.Value
    Next

    MsgBox (total)

    End Sub
```